# Why is my function iterating through rows instead of columns?

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply

I've written the following function

```
compareColumns <- function(x) {
  
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    paste("range", x, "=", range(x)) 
  } else if (is.integer(x)) {
    paste("table", x, "=", table(x)) 
  } else if (is.logical(x)) {
    paste("table", x, "=", table(x))
  } else if (is.character(x) & length(unique(x)) <= 15) {
    paste("table", x, "=", table (x))
  } else {
    paste("count unique", x, "=", length(unique(x)))
  }
    
}
```

I want the output to be the one I would get if I were doing all of those operations manually to each column such as

```
apply(df, 2, length)
```

*outputs:*

```
Column1                   Column2                   Column3             Column4                   
2115                      2115                      2115                2115
```

*or*

```
length(df$Column1)
```

*outputs*

```
2115
```

instead I get

```
apply(df, 2, compareColumns)
```

*outputs:*

```
Column1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   [1,] "count unique row1 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [2,] "count unique row2 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [3,] "count unique row3 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [4,] "count unique row4 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [5,] "count unique row5 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [6,] "count unique row6 = 212"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [7,] "count unique row7 = 212"
```

Where am I going wrong? Why won't my function apply to columns only?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lapply` instead of `apply` as `apply` converts to `matrix` and thus can have only a single `type` - i.e. if there is a single column that is `character`, it converts the whole into `character` class and thus got the same output with `apply` - i.e. it couldn't satisfy any of the conditions and thus goes into the `else` condition

```
lapply(df, compareColumns)
```

Also, as we are `paste`ing with `x` i.e. the column values, the `length` of the output will be the same as the number of rows

---

Check with a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
apply(iris, 2, compareColumns)
lapply(iris, compareColumns)
```